# How to use TODO files in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I created a file in VS Code named "todo" and it is displayed with a checkmark icon. I thought that this could be used somehow, but I didn't find any information about it.

It looks like this:

[image: what does it look like]

How can it be used?

Answer (score 9):

I was wondering exactly the same thing! I haven't been able to find any native functionality of VSCode that deals with ToDo files, however I did find ToDo Tree, a neat looking extension which will provide highlighting for any todo/bug(etc) comments, and also group them together in the activity bar.

[image]

[image]

Find more info on [Thomas Venturini's blog post](https://thomasventurini.com/articles/the-best-way-to-work-with-todos-in-vscode/)

Comment: Works nicely but wasn't finding keywords in latex comments until I added `"todo-tree.regex.regex": "((//|#|<!--|;|/\\*|^|%|\\\\)\\s*($TAGS)\\{*|^\\s*- \\[ \\])",` to my `settings.json`. I got the line from their wiki at `https://github.com/Gruntfuggly/todo-tree/wiki/Configuration-Examples`.

Answer (score 4):

It is just an icon indicating the file type.

VS Code doesn't have any native features for doing anything special with TODO files.

There may be extensions on the marketplace that could do something with the format.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a way to add some functionality with the todo files by using [the Todo+ extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-todo-plus).

Create a todo item with a hyphen and a space:

```
- Sample Todo Item
```

Mark todo items as complete by replacing the hyphen with a `+`, it should turn green.

```
+ Completed Todo Item
```

Text not following these formats will mark as a comment

```
Sample comment
```

At the bottom bar, there will be a percentage indicator of the number of tasks you have completed/have left.
Here is a picture of the [percentage indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDocn.png) and a [file example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqaYV.png).

You can right click on specific todo items to mark as cancelled and started, and done. This will use special symbols for the todo items as well as adding timestamps. I've found this to be a bit clutter for solo work, but could be useful in a team situation.

(edit: I thought it was built in, added extension link)